# What does the quote from Sgt. Apone in Aliens "Look into my eye" mean?

Tags: analysis, aliens

When the Marines are waking up you get this dialogue between Hudson and Apone:

*Hudson:* Man, this floor is freezing.

*Apone:* What do you want me to do, fetch your slippers for you?

*Hudson:* Gee, would you sir? I'd like that.

[*Apone* pulls down the skin under his left eye with middle finger]

*Apone:* Look into my eye.

What does the "Look into my eye" mean/suggest??

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's actually his right eye.

The common belief is that Apone is flipping Hudson [the bird](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_bird) (showing his middle finger). A gesture which means "f--- you".

It isn't obvious because Apone is also holding his cigar between the middle and forefinger of the same hand. This somewhat obscures the gesture.

But it's probably safe to assume that this is a well understood gesture in the military (at least in the fictional Aliens world), and in fact the gesture itself most likely isn't even necessary as anyone would understand the implication of just the words "look into my eye".

Answer (score 14):

Actually, it's short for, "Do you see a speck of 'give a shit' in my eye!"  We use to say it all the time when I first went in the Air Force back in the early 80's.  Basically, he didn't care if it was cold to them...

Comment: That makes sense, any reference to back it up?

Comment: In Poland it's for some reason "Can you see a tank rolling under my eyelid?" and is an expression invalidating some previous statement, just like in the movie. 

Don't know if pulling down your lower eyelid has common roots, it's actually a very interesting question.

Answer (score 8):

It's not the dialogue; it's the gesture. Apone is "flipping the bird" to Hudson -- an extended middle finger is an offensive gesture in the U.S. -- and using the line to call attention to it.

Comment: Sweet! I too was confused about this line, and didn't notice that he was flipping the bird.